# How do I set the style of menu items when hovering with the mouse

Tags: css, mmenu

I'm having trouble trying to style mmenu, I have found an example in the documentation that specifies a custom class for this but this is not working. I have tried variations with :hover on the  but this has not work either.

Code below

```css
.mm-listview li span:hover {
 font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Demo for Erika</title>



  <!-- MMENU: START (http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/) -->
  <!-- Include jQuery.mmenu .css files -->
  <link type="text/css" href="../mmenu/jquery.mmenu.all.css?v=6.1.7" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../mmenu/jquery.mmenu.all.js"></script>
        <link href="../mmenu/jquery.mmenu.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="../mmenu/jquery.mmenu.setselected.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  
  <!-- MMENU: END -->  
  
  
  
  <style type="text/css">
   
  </style>
  
 </head>

 <body>
  <!-- The page -->
  <div class="page">
   <div class="header">
    <a href="#my-menu" class='btn btn-success'>Demo</a>   
   </div>
   <div class="content">
    <p><strong>This is a demo.</strong><br />
    Click the menu icon to open the menu.</p>
   </div>
  </div>

  <!-- The menu -->
  <nav id="my-menu"> 
   <ul>
    <li>
     <span> <!-- http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/support/tips-and-tricks.html See: Open Submenus -->
      <h1>About us</h1>
      <p>This is a text explaining how things that are below this menu item. Don't be scared to click on it.</p>
     </span>  
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Annual Report</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    
   
 </ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

In case of mmenu, because a child element of the li is automatically added by mmenu to support screen readers, that new element, an anchor, has a position: absolute and has precedence over all other siblings having :hover events.

So in the light of this issue, the :hover has to be put on the parent element, here being the li element.

```
    .mm-listview li:hover {
       background-color:#ff6600;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what `mmenu` is, but I think `:hover` [css selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp) may be an answer.

Usage

```
 .active {
  text-decoration: underline;
  background-color: black;
}

/* Title of menu items */
.mm-listview li span h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: blue;
}

/* Title style on mouse hover */
.mm-listview li span h1:hover {
  /*css declarations;*/
}

/* Description of menu items */
.mm-listview li span p {
  font-size: 1em;
}           
/* item style on mouse hover */
.mm-listview li span p:hover {
  /*css declarations;*/
}
```

Comment: @core114 Oh, Thanks. But what he want to do (I mean, **_How do I set the style of menu items when hovering with the mouse_**) is simply done by just adding css :hover selector.

Comment: sir, i know ,that question is not clear ,anyway your answer's perfect

Comment: @core114 I agree with 'question is not clear'. Anyway, thank you. :)

Comment: Turns out that the issue was that mmenu (jQuery plugin) rewrites the <li> elements and wraps the children elements within an <a> tag which has a position: absolute.  In the case where siblings have competing :hover events, the one with the position:absolute takes precedence. This explains why putting a :hover on the span didn't work.